# Best XML Library in C++, Fast Set-Up

Tags: c++, xml, visual-studio

I was wondering what is the best XML Library in C++ (I'm using Visual Studio), considering fast set-up is critical. Basically, I want to create a file to save annotations on various .avi files.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What XML parser should I use in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387610/what-xml-parser-should-i-use-in-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to get [TinyXML](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml/) set up and working in a matter of minutes.

Comment: I agree tinyxml is pretty quick to set up and use

Comment: How would I link it in? Is it just with the one .lib that is built?

Comment: It's only a couple of source files, so you can either create a .lib and link to that, or (at least for a first attempt) you can just compile its source files along with your own.

Answer (score 2):

[TinyXML](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml/) is simple enough for almost all your use (if you don't bother having the whole xml representation in memory) but other libraries offer better important features :

- [RapidXML](http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/) is made to be really really fast. It's used in the [boost::property_tree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/property_tree.html) library for  the xml file read/write features. If you already use boost, using directly boost::property_tree might be a good idea, if adequate, as you already can easily use it with it's simple interface.
- [pugiXML](http://code.google.com/p/pugixml/) has been mentionned as a good replacement for RapidXML by someone on the boost mailing list, but I'm not aware of the differences.
- [Xerces-C++](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/) is made to allow you high level manipulations on xml like validation using xsd files -- but is really heavy on both speed and memory size...
- [wrappers around classic C xml libraries (like LibXML2)](http://www.alhem.net/project/xmlw/index.html) might be interesting choice if you don't find what you're looking for with the previous ones...

Answer (score 0):

I've used XercesC++ in the past and it was relatively painless to get working and working with.

I'm currently using MSXML and it is painful.