# XML parsing in C++

Tags: c++, xml

What's the best API I can use to do some simple XML read/writing? I'm using Visual Studios. Is there a standard one that I can use in the STD library? The sofwtare that I need it for maybe sold and can't be open source, so it will have to have a flexible license for commercial use.

EDIT: I am NOT using this for any SOAP, protocol or data-binding stuff, Im just using this to store information, as almost an alternative to a database (because in this instance it would be more efficient).

Comment: Duplicate Question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387610/what-xml-parser-should-i-use-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I love [pugixml](http://pugixml.org/). It's fast, light weight, incredibly easy to use and embed in projects (I've used it in several at work, it's only ~3 files), and best of all, supports XPath 1.0 (which is *awesome*).

**Edit**: No, there isn't one in the standard library.

**Edit Edit**: About pugixml's license: it is distributed under the MIT license, which is about as permissive as you can get.

Comment: True, but pugixml is not an [XML data binding tool](http://xmldatabinding.org). I don't like low level XML coding as its easy to mess up. You may end up having to write lots more code to store/retrieve XML data and check/convert content.

Comment: @Alex: Sure, if you're doing lots of complicated XML parsing, then a heavier-weight parser might be better. But the OP asked for a simple XML parser for some simple serialization. In the context of this question, a large library with XML data binding is overkill (especially since I seriously doubt the OP has a WSDL/XSD to generate the data bindings). Using something like gSOAP would be overcomplicated overkill for the OP.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there's no standard library to read XML.

I found TinyXML a handy library. There's [now a TinyXML 2](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml2/index.html) which I've not used.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommand [GSOAP](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html). I know companies that use this in products they sell so licensing should not be an issue. It has features such as schema validation etc...

Comment: That's great, Ill check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft offers an XML library called XmlLite.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms752838%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: This looks cool, do you know about licencing stuff here? Thanks.

Comment: Not sure, but we use it in our product so it can't be something restrictive.