# RapidXML NULL Pointer

Tags: c++, xml, memory, memory-leaks, rapidxml

I'm getting values of my config file with rapidXML in a kindly bad way.

```
xml_document<> doc;
doc.parse<parse_full>(buffer);
int a = atoi(doc.first_node("master")->first_node("profile")->first_node("width")->value());
```

If the node doesn't exist "first_node" return 0 so "->value()" crash. Returning a new xml_node will fix the crash but what about the memory leaks?

This is the rapidXML's fonction with the old and new return :

```
    xml_node<Ch> *first_node(const Ch *name = 0, std::size_t name_size = 0, bool case_sensitive = true) const
    {
        if (name)
        {
            if (name_size == 0)
                name_size = internal::measure(name);
            for (xml_node<Ch> *child = m_first_node; child; child = child->next_sibling())
                if (internal::compare(child->name(), child->name_size(), name, name_size, case_sensitive))
                    return child;
            return new xml_node<Ch>(node_document);
            //return 0;
        }
        else
            return m_first_node;
    }
```

Comment: You should check that each node in the chain exist instead of changing the library to return a new empty node. That _will_ create memory leaks.

Comment: I don't wanna check for each node to exist before reaching the next one. I would like to be able to shorten the lines like : doc.first_node("master/profile/width").value() without checking if I got a NULL pointer. Do you find this more user friendly? Also, how do I avoid memory leaks. How the newly created element to be destroyed automatically?

Comment: For avoiding memory leaks, you should probably look into [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory).

Answer (score 0):

You should use exceptions, like:

```
int a;
try
{
    xml_document<> doc;
    doc.parse<parse_full>(buffer);
    a = atoi(doc.first_node("master")->first_node("profile")->first_node("width")->value());
}
catch(NodeNotExists &ex)
{
    // process error condition
}
```

Also, if don't want to change rapidxml code, use wrapper function like:

```
template<typename T>
T* notnull(T* arg)
{
    if (arg == 0)
        throw NodeNotExists();
    return arg;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on hate-engine's answer, I created a class of static helper functions to handle this situation by wrapping the node value access. Check out my answer over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19570357/1329160). You could expand upon that or pursue something more along the lines of a xpath-style of node access (which I don't believe is built-in to RapidXML currently but [others do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9387612/1329160)).

Edit: You could create a wrapper function with that takes a simple xpath-like path and combine that with one of my wrappers to get something like...

```
int a = GetNodeInt(GetFirstNodePath(doc, "master/profile/width"), 0);
```

Where GetNodeInt and GetFirstNodePath are defined something like this...

```
    int GetNodeInt(rapidxml::xml_base<>* node, int DefaultValue)
    {
        int temp;
        try
        {
            if (node == 0) return DefaultValue;
            if (sscanf(node->value(), "%d", &temp) != 1) return DefaultValue;
            return temp;
        }
        catch (...) { return DefaultValue; }
    }

    // Find node with simple path from current node such as "first/second/third"
    rapidxml::xml_node<>* GetFirstNodePath(rapidxml::xml_node<>* root, const char *path)
    {
        xml_node<>* node = root;
        char* last = (char*)path; // only using this pointer to read
        char* cur = last;
        if (cur == 0 || root == 0) return 0;
        while (node)
        {
            if (*cur == '/' || *cur == 0)
            {
                if (cur != last) node = node->first_node(last,cur-last);
                if (*cur == 0) break;
                last = cur + 1;
            }
            ++cur;
        }
        return node;
    }
```

Now this code has not been thoroughly tested, but gives you the general idea.