# Very simple C/C++ XML Parser

Tags: c++, c, xml, linux, xml-parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What XML parser should I use in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387610/what-xml-parser-should-i-use-in-c)

It is generally required to parse application settings from local XML file under Linux platform and nothing more.

Requirements:
 1. Can be used for commercial product
 2. Free of charge
 3. Easy to install (1 header file will be great)
 4. Easy to use
 5. Very stable
 6. Unicode support

Comment: Perhaps helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387610/what-xml-parser-should-i-use-in-c

Comment: I _think_ TinyXML is what you want, not sure if it meets the commerical requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I think [expat](http://expat.sourceforge.net/) does everything you want.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Apache's xerces-c](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/). It never gave me problems and you can find some useful info on Google, like: [Tuto1](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/XML-Xerces-C.html).
Also, it is free of charge and you can use it commercial products.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at boost::property_tree http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/property_tree.html