# How to utilise xml files in marmalade

Tags: xml, windows-phone-8, marmalade

I want to create a custom xml file to store data very simply. I want to know what is the best was to create and read xml files using Marmalade and how to use this.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

There's a very exhaustive list of XML parsers which can be used in c++ [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387610/what-xml-parser-should-i-use-in-c).

If it's a pain for you to create a marmalade subproject using c++ libraries and you're flexible enough for storage method, you can instead use [cJson port for Marmalade](https://github.com/strobe/cJSON-for-marmalade), and can store data in json files instead. I've used this in many of my projects and it never gave me any chance to complain yet.