# Get specific portion of text from string in C

Tags: c, string

For a program I am working on I need to get info from a specific area from an online xml document. Right now I have save the xml as a string and then use `press=xml.substr(1906,5);` to get what I need from it. This is one line I pull info from: `<pressure_in>30.17</pressure_in>` The problem with this is that if the value between is longer than the specified length, (5 characters in this case) I cant get the desired value. How could I get it reliably?

Comment: [Use a real XML parser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387610/what-xml-parser-should-i-use-in-c)

Comment: If you're able to get that line without an full blown XML parser, just use a simple regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main ()
{
    // sample string below:
    char* xmlText = "<pressure_in>30.17134</pressure_in>";
    int n = strlen(xmlText);
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
        if (isdigit(xmlText[i]) || xmlText[i] == '.') {
            // store result or just print:
            printf("%c",xmlText[i]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n")
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
30.17134
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me figure out what to do.

Answer (score 1):

First convert the string to an xml structure, then extract what you need with an XPath selector. A very simple example can be found here:

http://xmlsoft.org/tutorial/apd.html