# How to read an xhtml file in c++?

Tags: c++, g++

How to read an html file in c++??
for example i have following file and i want to read it in c++ and want to store it in a structure variable

```
<ProjectInput>
<Configuration>
<SchedulingPolicy> FCFS </SchedulingPolicy>
<preemptive> yes </preemeptive>
<NumberOfDisks> 7 </NumberOfDisks> 
...
...
```

Comment: I suggest you to use boost c++ and property tree. Take a look here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_propertytree/parsers.html

Comment: You should use an XML parser for that : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387610/what-xml-parser-should-i-use-in-c/9387612#9387612

Comment: Go visit the libraries, they have examples. Nobody is going to write it for you.