# What is the most efficient way to parse large xml files?

Tags: c++, xml, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc

So I got this new project where the program has to parse a bunch of xml files and write the data to a database. There are 12 to 14 xml files, ~75 MB in total, with a few large ones, one example here has 32529797 characters. The task is to parse them as fast as possible.

My experience with xml is a little mnore than basic. A few solutions with a DOM parser (tinyXML). The files had no more than 100 lines.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and this will be a MFC application without an interface. I'm thinking about a SAX parser, maybe MSXML.

I'm sure there are some xml experts here and I'm asking you for your opinion/advice on this task. What would be the most efficient way to parse those xml files?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387610/what-xml-parser-should-i-use-in-c/9387612#9387612

Comment: Beware: asking for recommendations on libraries/external resources is off-topic, so you might want to recenter the question on how best to use MSXML (for example), and if you do so I would expect that you be able to provide examples of code you wrote that you find sub-par. Also... are you sure that 75 MB is big? If you process those files one at a time, most libraries should deal with them without any issue whatsoever; and you can just benchmark for the performance.