# How to parse txt file from middle to particular string using C++?

Tags: c++

I have to parse a TXT file of XML messages and save the ID value in another file. I can reach up to the `<ID>` tag using find function. But how to get the value, also the length of value varies.

```xml
<note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <ID>Fx12345</ID>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
<note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Alex</from>
    <ID>Fx1236785</ID>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

I'm using this approach

```
while (!fileInput.eof()) {
   getline(fileInput, line);
    if ((offset = line.find("<ID>", 0)) != string::npos) {
        // How to get only value
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest using a proper XML parsing library rather than rolling your own fragile parser.

Comment: I would like to add a link to [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9387612/2700399) to what @cdhowie already said.

Comment: I would appreciate if anyone can share the logic atleast it will improve my concepts

Comment: _@Abhi _"atleast it will improve my concepts"_ Your _concept_ is very likely to fail parsing XML text properly. You should stick with @cdhowie's advice.

Comment: Most, if not all of the libraries in the answer I've linked are open source. Study their code to improve your concepts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`string::find()` has an overload that specifies the position to start the search. So simply start a second search, starting at the end of `<ID>`, to look for `</ID>`. You are after what comes in between the two. Pretty simple really.

However, as suggested elsewhere, there are a lot of XML parsers out there. Using a full XML parser would be recommended if the input file could have some variations.