# Boost read_xml issue parsing string?

Tags: c++, xml, boost, boost-propertytree

I'm trying to parse this string and retrieve the "sid" and the "Type". I have the following code. It is crashing at the `get_child` line and I'm not entirely sure why...

```
const boost::property_tree::ptree& empty_ptree(){
static boost::property_tree::ptree t;
return t;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
struct SXMLElements
{
    std::string strSessionId;
    unsigned int uiTypeOfNotification;
};

std::string strXMLText = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\r\n" 
"<NotificationSet vers=\"1.0\" svcid=\"session\" notid=\"42\">\r\n" "<Notification><![CDATA[<SessionNotification vers=\"1.0\" notid=\"42\">\r\n"
"<Session sid=\"sdfkljdsfkjjsf\">\r\n" "<Property name=\"CharSet\" value=\"UTF-8\"></Property>\r\n" 
"</Session>\r\n" "<Type>5</Type>\r\n" 
"<Time>324242</Time>\r\n" 
"</SessionNotification>]]></Notification>\r\n" 
"</NotificationSet>";

//// Parse the HTTP header Status line.
std::stringstream ss( strXMLText );

boost::property_tree::ptree xmlResponse;
//if (strXMLText.size() > 0)
//{
std::istringstream isResponse (strXMLText);
boost::property_tree::read_xml(isResponse, xmlResponse);
SXMLElements sXmlElem;
//const boost::property_tree::ptree & formats = xmlResponse.get_child("NotificationSet.Notification.Session", empty_ptree());
BOOST_FOREACH( boost::property_tree::ptree::value_type const& v, xmlResponse.get_child("NotificationSet.Notification.SessionNotification.Session") )
{
    sXmlElem.strSessionId = xmlResponse.get<std::string>("<xmlattr>.sid", "");
    sXmlElem.uiTypeOfNotification = xmlResponse.get<unsigned int>("Type", 0);
    //  }
}
//}

return 0;
}
```

Can anyone spot what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Hehe. To the edit, I also provided the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The `Session` attribute `cd=""\"o=rrs,o=ces,maxtime=""\"64""\"` decodes to

```
cd="o=rrs,o=ces,maxtime="64"
```

which leaves invalid XML.

Regardless, all the `""\"` could be replaced by just `\"`

Besides that, a simple test revealed that Boost Property Tree doesn't like `<![CDATA[]]>` sections, and rightly so: [What does <![CDATA[]]> in XML mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784183/what-does-cdata-in-xml-mean/2784200#2784200)

> In an XML document or external parsed entity, a CDATA section is a section of element content that is marked for the parser to interpret as only character data, not markup. [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA)

**SUMMARY**

- Boost Property Tree is ***not*** an XML parsing library ([xml parsing using boost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28037909/xml-parsing-using-boost/28041081#28041081))
- CDATA segments are ***not*** XML (so even using an XML library you shouldn't expect to parse it directly)

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d38a5c46666d565d)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string const strXMLText = R"(<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> 
    <NotificationSet vers="1.0" svcid="session" notid="42">
        <Notification><SessionNotification vers="1.0" notid="42">
                <Session sid="sdfkljdsfkjjsf" stype="user" cid="uid=1,u=People,dc=r,dc=c" cd="o=rrs,o=ces,maxtime=64" maxidle="24">
                    <Property name="CharSet" value="UTF-8"></Property>
                    <Property name="ed" value="xxx"></Property>
                    <Property name="Sdle" value="sdl:asdadsad"></Property>
                </Session>
                <Type>5</Type>
                <Time>324242</Time>
        </SessionNotification></Notification>
    </NotificationSet>
    )";

    //// Parse the HTTP header Status line.
    std::stringstream ss(strXMLText);

    boost::property_tree::ptree xmlResponse;

    std::istringstream isResponse (strXMLText);
    boost::property_tree::read_xml(isResponse, xmlResponse);

    if (auto SessionNotification = xmlResponse.get_child_optional("NotificationSet.Notification.SessionNotification"))
    {
        struct SessionElement {
            std::string id;
            unsigned int uiTypeOfNotification;
        };

        if (auto Session = SessionNotification->get_child_optional("Session")) {
            SessionElement elem {
                Session->get("<xmlattr>.sid", ""),
                SessionNotification->get("Type", 0u)
            };

            std::cout << "id: " << elem.id << ", type: " << elem.uiTypeOfNotification << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Prints

```
id: sdfkljdsfkjjsf, type: 5
```

Comment: std::string strXMLText = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\r\n"
       "<NotificationSet vers=\"1.0\" svcid=\"session\" notid=\"42\">\r\n"
       "<Notification><![CDATA[<SessionNotification vers=\"1.0\" notid=\"42\">\r\n"
       "<Session sid=\"sdfkljdsfkjjsf\">\r\n"
       "<Property name=\"CharSet\" value=\"UTF-8\"></Property>\r\n"
       "</Session>\r\n"
       "<Type>5</Type>\r\n"
       "<Time>324242</Time>\r\n"
       "</SessionNotification>]]></Notification>\r\n"
       "</NotificationSet>";

Comment: That's what I have now Sehe, but i'm getting an exception still being thrown in the "xmlResponse.get_child("NotificationSet.Notification.SessionNotification.Session")" part.....

Comment: Because of the CDATA, does that mean i can't use Boost Property Tree? What else could i use?

Comment: Please, @suzan, update your question. Comments don't work for this - at all. I've updated my answer

Comment: Thanks @sehe, i've updated my code. The xml i initially had with the CDATA was from a demo HTTP POST request with content set to xml. Are you saying that when i receive the POST request with the xml content, that the CDATA won't be in there?

Comment: It probably shouldn't. But I can't tell. Because what you receive depends _only_ on what the server sends. And the server may send you a Shakespeare drama if it so chooses...

Comment: Hah... great. So if it DID send it with the CDATA part, then what is the best thing to do...?

Comment: You use the library that already exists to handle it. Preferrably not in C++. If you must, you grovel and growl and extract the CDATA using [a proper XML library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387610/what-xml-parser-should-i-use-in-c/9387612#9387612) and parse its XML content /after that/. You could consider doing a quick-and-dirty CDATA removal preprocessing step. But it's hard to get right and kills XML compliance anyways

Comment: When you say use the library that already exists to handle it, what library are we talking about exactly?

Comment: Please. I linked to that answer twice now. Read it. Thank you.

Comment: Ok so TinyXML is an option. Good... Maybe I can try and rewrite this with TinyXML