# Replacement of hash variable of perl in c/c++

Tags: c++, c, perl

I am trying to convert Perl code into c++ but facing problem to convert hash variable. map is the option to convert but it wont work for some cases.

```
my %xyz =( "x1" => {"z"=>1,
                "y"=>0,
                "a"=>2})
```

in c++

```
map<string,map<string, int> > xyz;
```

and we can use `insert or emplace` to store values in xyz but for below declaration, how we can use map or any other option available  in c/c++

```
my %xyz = ("x1" => {"z" => 1,
                    "y"=> 0,
                    "a"=> {"y1"=>0 }},
           "x2" => {"Version"=> "x.300 x.400 x.500   x.600"})
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Create a class that can either have a single integer value or be a map of strings to instances of itself. You could probably also use almost any JSON library -- they usually provide just such a discriminated value class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of instead of using the `std::map`, you can store xyz variable as an `xml` format string or a `json` format string.
XML format will look like as shown below.

```
<xyz>
  <x1>
    <z>1</z>
    <y>0</y>
    <a>
      <y1>0</y1>
    </a>
  </x1>
  <x2>
    <Version>x.300 x.400 x.500  x.600 </Version>
  </x2>
</xyz>
```

Then you can use the xml parser. [What XML parser should I use in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387610/what-xml-parser-should-i-use-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

Use a JSON library such as [jsoncpp](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp). The following JSON object encodes the same information as your example:

```
{
    "x1" :
    {
         "z" : 1,
         "y" : 0,
         "a" :
         {
             "y1" : 0
         }
    }
    "x2" :
    {
        "Version" : "x.300 x.400 x.500   x.600"
    }
}
```