# C++ - Getting string of text inbetween character and text

Tags: c++, string, console, extract

I'm making a console program that will get a line of text that starts with a specific character. I'm working with an .txt file as the input of text, and this is it:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector android:height="64.0dip" android:width="64.0dip" android:viewportWidth="24.0" android:viewportHeight="24.0"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:pathData="M12.05,7.7c-1.1,0,-2,0.94,-2,2.05v0.5h4v-0.5C14.05,8.65,13.15,7.7,12.05,7.7z" />
    <path android:fillColor="@*common:color/qs_toggles_color" android:pathData="M15.05,10.25l0.0,-0.5c0.0,-1.66 -1.34,-3.0 -3.0,-3.0s-2.99,1.34 -2.99,3.0l-0.01,0.5c-0.55,0.0 -1.0,0.45 -1.0,1.0l0.0,5.0c0.0,0.55 0.45,1.0 1.0,1.0l6.0,0.0c0.55,0.0 1.0,-0.45 1.0,-1.0l0.0,-5.0C16.05,10.7 15.6,10.25 15.05,10.25zM12.05,14.75c-0.55,0.0 -1.0,-0.45 -1.0,-1.0c0.0,-0.55 0.45,-1.0 1.0,-1.0s1.0,0.45 1.0,1.0C13.05,14.3 12.6,14.75 12.05,14.75zM14.05,10.25l-4.0,0.0l0.0,-0.5c0.0,-1.1 0.9,-2.05 2.0,-2.05s2.0,0.94 2.0,2.05L14.05,10.25z" />
    <path android:fillColor="@*common:color/qs_toggles_color" android:pathData="M16.5,2.5c3.3,1.5 5.6,4.7 6.0,8.5L24.0,11.0C23.4,4.8 18.3,0.0 12.0,0.0c-0.2,0.0 -0.4,0.0 -0.7,0.0l3.8,3.8L16.5,2.5zM7.5,21.5c-3.3,-1.5 -5.6,-4.7 -6.0,-8.5L0.1,13.0C0.6,19.2 5.7,24.0 12.0,24.0c0.2,0.0 0.4,0.0 0.7,0.0l-3.8,-3.8L7.5,21.5z" />
</vector>
```

What I want to do is extract

```
M12.05,7.7c-1.1,0,-2,0.94,-2,2.05v0.5h4v-0.5C14.05,8.65,13.15,7.7,12.05,7.7z
```

and:

```html
M15.05,10.25l0.0,-0.5c0.0,-1.66 -1.34,-3.0 -3.0,-3.0s-2.99,1.34 -2.99,3.0l-0.01,0.5c-0.55,0.0 -1.0,0.45 -1.0,1.0l0.0,5.0c0.0,0.55 0.45,1.0 1.0,1.0l6.0,0.0c0.55,0.0 1.0,-0.45 1.0,-1.0l0.0,-5.0C16.05,10.7 15.6,10.25 15.05,10.25zM12.05,14.75c-0.55,0.0 -1.0,-0.45 -1.0,-1.0c0.0,-0.55 0.45,-1.0 1.0,-1.0s1.0,0.45 1.0,1.0C13.05,14.3 12.6,14.75 12.05,14.75zM14.05,10.25l-4.0,0.0l0.0,-0.5c0.0,-1.1 0.9,-2.05 2.0,-2.05s2.0,0.94 2.0,2.05L14.05,10.25z
```

and:

```html
M16.5,2.5c3.3,1.5 5.6,4.7 6.0,8.5L24.0,11.0C23.4,4.8 18.3,0.0 12.0,0.0c-0.2,0.0 -0.4,0.0 -0.7,0.0l3.8,3.8L16.5,2.5zM7.5,21.5c-3.3,-1.5 -5.6,-4.7 -6.0,-8.5L0.1,13.0C0.6,19.2 5.7,24.0 12.0,24.0c0.2,0.0 0.4,0.0 0.7,0.0l-3.8,-3.8L7.5,21.5z
```

and put them into their own strings. I have tried to do this by deleting all of the text before those strings and after, but I get an Unhandled exception, with this code:

```html
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    string str = "<?xml versim on=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?> <vector android:height=\"64.0dip\" android:width=\"64.0dip\" android:viewportWidth=\"24.0\" android:viewportHeight=\"24.0\" xmlns:android=\"http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android\"> <path android:fillColor=\"#00000000\" android:pathData=\"M12.05,7.7c-1.1,0,-2,0.94,-2,2.05v0.5h4v-0.5C14.05,8.65,13.15,7.7,12.05,7.7z\" /> <path android:fillColor=\"@*common:color/qs_toggles_color\" android:pathData=\"M15.05,10.25l0.0,-0.5c0.0,-1.66 -1.34,-3.0 -3.0,-3.0s-2.99,1.34 -2.99,3.0l-0.01,0.5c-0.55,0.0 -1.0,0.45 -1.0,1.0l0.0,5.0c0.0,0.55 0.45,1.0 1.0,1.0l6.0,0.0c0.55,0.0 1.0,-0.45 1.0,-1.0l0.0,-5.0C16.05,10.7 15.6,10.25 15.05,10.25zM12.05,14.75c-0.55,0.0 -1.0,-0.45 -1.0,-1.0c0.0,-0.55 0.45,-1.0 1.0,-1.0s1.0,0.45 1.0,1.0C13.05,14.3 12.6,14.75 12.05,14.75zM14.05,10.25l-4.0,0.0l0.0,-0.5c0.0,-1.1 0.9,-2.05 2.0,-2.05s2.0,0.94 2.0,2.05L14.05,10.25z\" <path android:fillColor=\"@*common:color/qs_toggles_color\" android:pathData=\"M16.5,2.5c3.3,1.5 5.6,4.7 6.0,8.5L24.0,11.0C23.4,4.8 18.3,0.0 12.0,0.0c-0.2,0.0 -0.4,0.0 -0.7,0.0l3.8,3.8L16.5,2.5zM7.5,21.5c-3.3,-1.5 -5.6,-4.7 -6.0,-8.5L0.1,13.0C0.6,19.2 5.7,24.0 12.0,24.0c0.2,0.0 0.4,0.0 0.7,0.0l-3.8,-3.8L7.5,21.5z\" /> </vector>";
    string dp1= str;
    dp1.replace(dp1.find("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?> <vector android:height=\"64.0dip\" android:width=\"64.0dip\" android:viewportWidth=\"24.0\" android:viewportHeight=\"24.0\" xmlns:android=\"http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android\"> <path android:fillColor=\"#00000000\" android:pathData=\""), 269, "");
    dp1.replace(dp1.find("/> <path android:fillColor=\"@*common:color/qs_toggles_color\" android:pathData=\"M15.05,10.25l0.0,-0.5c0.0,-1.66 -1.34,-3.0 -3.0,-3.0s-2.99,1.34 -2.99,3.0l-0.01,0.5c-0.55,0.0 -1.0,0.45 -1.0,1.0l0.0,5.0c0.0,0.55 0.45,1.0 1.0,1.0l6.0,0.0c0.55,0.0 1.0,-0.45 1.0,-1.0l0.0,-5.0C16.05,10.7 15.6,10.25 15.05,10.25zM12.05,14.75c-0.55,0.0 -1.0,-0.45 -1.0,-1.0c0.0,-0.55 0.45,-1.0 1.0,-1.0s1.0,0.45 1.0,1.0C13.05,14.3 12.6,14.75 12.05,14.75zM14.05,10.25l-4.0,0.0l0.0,-0.5c0.0,-1.1 0.9,-2.05 2.0,-2.05s2.0,0.94 2.0,2.05L14.05,10.25z/> <path android:fillColor=\"@*common:color/qs_toggles_color\" android:pathData=\"M15.05,10.25l0.0,-0.5c0.0,-1.66 -1.34,-3.0 -3.0,-3.0s-2.99,1.34 -2.99,3.0l-0.01,0.5c-0.55,0.0 -1.0,0.45 -1.0,1.0l0.0,5.0c0.0,0.55 0.45,1.0 1.0,1.0l6.0,0.0c0.55,0.0 1.0,-0.45 1.0,-1.0l0.0,-5.0C16.05,10.7 15.6,10.25 15.05,10.25zM12.05,14.75c-0.55,0.0 -1.0,-0.45 -1.0,-1.0c0.0,-0.55 0.45,-1.0 1.0,-1.0s1.0,0.45 1.0,1.0C13.05,14.3 12.6,14.75 12.05,14.75zM14.05,10.25l-4.0,0.0l0.0,-0.5c0.0,-1.1 0.9,-2.05 2.0,-2.05s2.0,0.94 2.0,2.05L14.05,10.25z\" <path android:fillColor=\"@*common:color/qs_toggles_color\" android:pathData=\"M16.5,2.5c3.3,1.5 5.6,4.7 6.0,8.5L24.0,11.0C23.4,4.8 18.3,0.0 12.0,0.0c-0.2,0.0 -0.4,0.0 -0.7,0.0l3.8,3.8L16.5,2.5zM7.5,21.5c-3.3,-1.5 -5.6,-4.7 -6.0,-8.5L0.1,13.0C0.6,19.2 5.7,24.0 12.0,24.0c0.2,0.0 0.4,0.0 0.7,0.0l-3.8,-3.8L7.5,21.5z\" /> </vector>\""), 525, "");

    std::cout << dp1 << endl;

    system ("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

So basically, I want to extract those 3 strings mentioned above into their own strings. I was thinking I could extract them based on their starting character, which is M. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to extract data from an XML file would be to use an XML parser. If your XML file changed, you would have problems with the manual search of strings you are trying to perform.

[What XML parser should I use in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387610/what-xml-parser-should-i-use-in-c)

Comment: Thanks, I found TinyXML and I'm using that for now