# Reading HTML text using C++

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I am currently reading book from Allex Allain and there is practice problem: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c17F6.jpg)

And i dont know how to think about this problem and i am somehow stuck , should i first find every tag and save it to array or vector ? and then compare tags from vector with original string ? and make som conditions ? I dont looking for code from you i want to solve it by myself i am just looking for inspiration or some ideas , or some useful methods i could use. thank you.

Comment: Not a good idea to include an image of text. Cannot be searched nor useful on a mobile phone

Answer (score 1):

You should make a Parser.

Read each word and if you find tag then find the next `<tag>`. If this is the opposite tag `</tag>` then you could create object from that tag.

Solution proposed imply to create interface named tag and derived class named `<html>`, `<head>`.

So in final you will have a motor (parser) which eats text and produces object.

Answer (score 0):

Yes like @MSD561 he could write a parser. Either from scratch
and reinvent the wheel, or use a library.

An XML-library can be used to achieve the second and get a better understanding for the structures:

[What XML parser should I use in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387610/what-xml-parser-should-i-use-in-c)

It will also provide you with all the entries for the tags etc and you'll just have to parse through the xml tree.

Comment: HTML is not guaranteed to be valid XML -- only XHTML is. If you want to use an XML parser on HTML you need to run it through a converter first, such as tidylib.

Comment: @mmoment as I understand he is currently learning so it is makes sense to implement a basic parser in order to understand inner mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

```
using namespace std;

void main ()
{
    ifstream x; 
    string name,head="<html><head></head><body><table>", tail="</table></body></html>", bodystart="<tr><td>",bodyclose="</td></tr>";
    ofstream y;
    x.open("example.txt");
    y.open("myhtmlfile.html");
    y<<head;
    while(!x.eof())
    {
        x>>name; 
        y<<bodystart<<name<<bodyclose;
    }
    y<<tail;

    x.close();
    cout<<"\n\n";
}
```