# How to read xml file in c++

Tags: c++, xml

I have a xml file with the following code:

Contact.xml:

```
<ArrayOfPerson xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <Person>
            <ID>8a5049d9-2b1a-426f-ae15-50c8ccdc2812</ID>
            <Name>Jack</Name>
            <PhoneNumber>0125437689</PhoneNumber>
            <Key>a</Key>
            <State>false</State>
            <IsAccountBtalk>false</IsAccountBtalk>
            <IsAccountSupportBtalk>false</IsAccountSupportBtalk>
            <IsFriends>false</IsFriends>
            <IsFamily>false</IsFamily>
            <IsLock>false</IsLock>
            <Email />
            <Facebook />
            <JID>84125437689@bmail.vn</JID>
            <ImageUrl>Images/bkav_ic_avatar_default_0.png</ImageUrl>
            <IsFavorite>false</IsFavorite>
            <HasSendVCard>false</HasSendVCard>
          </Person>
          <Person>
            <ID>51ccd2c2-6ede-48d8-a93c-901a3ac6a84c</ID>
            <Name>Jony</Name>
            <PhoneNumber>015487887</PhoneNumber>
            <Key>a</Key>
            <State>false</State>
            <IsAccountBtalk>false</IsAccountBtalk>
            <IsAccountSupportBtalk>false</IsAccountSupportBtalk>
            <IsFriends>false</IsFriends>
            <IsFamily>false</IsFamily>
            <IsLock>false</IsLock>
            <Email />
            <Facebook />
            <JID>8415487887@bmail.vn</JID>
            <ImageUrl>Images/bkav_ic_avatar_default_1.png</ImageUrl>
            <IsFavorite>false</IsFavorite>
            <HasSendVCard>false</HasSendVCard>
          </Person>
          <Person>
            <ID>b8e5d059-c015-45ef-9826-c6b90bdbb463</ID>
            <Name>Shyn</Name>
            <PhoneNumber>0123456789</PhoneNumber>
            <Key>A</Key>
            <State>false</State>
            <IsAccountBtalk>false</IsAccountBtalk>
            <IsAccountSupportBtalk>false</IsAccountSupportBtalk>
            <IsFriends>false</IsFriends>
            <IsFamily>false</IsFamily>
            <IsLock>false</IsLock>
            <Email />
            <Facebook />
            <JID>84123456789@bmail.vn</JID>
            <ImageUrl>Images/bkav_ic_avatar_default_2.png</ImageUrl>
            <IsFavorite>false</IsFavorite>
            <HasSendVCard>false</HasSendVCard>
          </Person>
</ArrayOfPerson>
```

How do I read this XML?
How do I pass the a phone number and retrieve the name wearer it?
eg:0125437689 =>result:Jack

Comment: You need to parse xml file. Once parse, you'd get DOM representation of xml using which you can retrieve the elements. If you are looking for a parser, google "tinyxml"

Comment: Also, check out this excellent post: [What XML parser should I use in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387610/what-xml-parser-should-i-use-in-c).

Comment: i can't edit my question:(

Comment: I recommend [pugixml](http://pugixml.org/) library.

Comment: I recommend tinyxml2: http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml2/index.html

Comment: thanks all.i used tinyxml and success!