# Regex for single match of the xml tag's content

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I have a string:

```
<tag1 qwer=123>Hello</tag1>
```

And I want a regex that will have a single match for its inner content:

```
Hello
```

Using the following code:

```
string s = "<tag1>Hello</tag1>";
smatch sm;
regex re("<tag1>([\\s\\S]*?)</tag1>");
regex_match(s, sm, re);
```

I get one match and one its submatch:

```
<tag1>Hello</tag1>
Hello
```

What regex should I use to get simply one match:

```
Hello
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should learn the difference between match and capture group

Comment: There is no way to do that with an ECMAScript regex because it does not support lookbehinds. Besides, it is no big deal to access the capturing group value, you already know how to do it.

Comment: Use an existing XML library.  See [softwarerecs.se].

Comment: Parsing XML with regex is the worst idea ever. Use a library like PugiXML.

Comment: Use an XML parser. See [What XML parser should I use in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9387612/147845).

Answer (score 2):

This works for valid single-line XML tags:

```
regex re("[<][^>]+[>]([^<]+)[<]\/[^>]+[>]");
```