# End tag xml validation incorrect in Boost ptree read xml

Tags: c++, xml, boost, boost-propertytree

I am trying to do some simple xml parsing using Boost Ptrees in C++. However it seems like the `read_xml` function only throws an error if there is no end tag present. The below throws an error.
For eg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Grandparent>
<Parent>test<Parent>
</Grandparent>
```

Note the end tag of Parent doesnt have a closing forward slash and this is thrown as an error. Even the lack of closing tag like `<Parent>test` throws a valid error which is expected.

However if closing tag string doesnt match with the opening tag string it does not throw an error. For eg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Grandparent>
<Parent>test</Child>
</Grandparent>
```

The above parses just fine. My code is very simple as below:

```
using boost::property_tree::ptree;
ptree pt;
read_xml(xmlpath, pt);
```

Is there any thing that I am overlooking here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Most importantly: Boost Property Tree is not an XML library.

Secondly, the rapidxml implementation used under the hood has closing-tag validation as opt-in:

```
if (Flags & parse_validate_closing_tags)
{
    // Skip and validate closing tag name
    Ch *closing_name = text;
    skip<node_name_pred, Flags>(text);
    if (!internal::compare(node->name(), node->name_size(), closing_name, text - closing_name, true))
        BOOST_PROPERTY_TREE_RAPIDXML_PARSE_ERROR("invalid closing tag name", text);
}
```

Luck has it that Boost Property didn't opt-in. In fact, it doesn't *let you* opt in:

```
/// Text elements should be put in separate keys,
/// not concatenated in parent data.
static const int no_concat_text  = 0x1;
/// Comments should be omitted.
static const int no_comments     = 0x2;
/// Whitespace should be collapsed and trimmed.
static const int trim_whitespace = 0x4;

inline bool validate_flags(int flags)
{
    return (flags & ~(no_concat_text | no_comments | trim_whitespace)) == 0;
}
```

No other flags are allowed.

I suggest you turn to an XML library if you need XML parsing.

Comment: I was wondering if there is a SAX xml parser that you could suggest that works both for windows and linux? Finding it quite difficult to run libxml2 on windows. Running into all kinds of library linking errors.

Comment: I usually prefer PugiXML. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387610/what-xml-parser-should-i-use-in-c