# Structures with variable number of members and bitfields from the array

Tags: c++, templates, struct, bit-fields

I have many structures, which looks like:

```
struct S {
float a;
uint8_t b;
uint8_t c : 4; 
uint8_t d : 2; 
uint8_t e : 1; 
uint8_t f : 1; 
uint8_t g : 1;

...

} __attribute__((packed));
```

Number of members, their names, type and size of bit fields are different.
I need create this structures according to data from xml.

```
<S>
<a type="float", size=""/>
<a type="uint8_t", size=""/>
<a type="uint8_t", size="4"/>
<a type="uint8_t", size="2"/>
<a type="uint8_t", size="1"/>
<a type="uint8_t", size="1"/>
<a type="uint8_t", size="1"/>
</S>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you what to create C source code based on this XML file or do you want to somehow create these structures in run-time in the same program that's reading the XML? It would be better if you mentioned what do you need this for.

Comment: I need to be able add or change structures without a recompile of the project

Comment: What exactly are you doing with those structures in your project?

Comment: I send them via udp

Answer (score 0):

Out of topic, but you can thing about using a library such as [cTemplate](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/OlafvdSpek/ctemplate/blob/master/doc/index.html) to generate your code, and a [XML Parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387610/what-xml-parser-should-i-use-in-c).

Next time try  : https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/