# c++ Read contents of xml file

Tags: c++, xml, tinyxml

I am still learning c++ and need some help reading the contents of an xml file.

Here's the format of my xml file:

```
<Rotary>
  <UserInformation>
    <Name>myName</Name>
    <Age>myAge</Age>
  </UserInformation>
</Rotary>
```

My c++ program needs to read the values of Name and Age so that I can check it on a SQL DB. I'm really struggling with using tinyxml. Someone gave me some code to try to help me, but I'm still not getting it. Here's the code below:

```
    TiXmlHandle docHandle(&doc);

    string tinyData = "null";

    TiXmlNode* tinySet = docHandle.FirstChild("Rotary").FirstChild("UserInformation").ToNode();

    if (tinySet)
    {
        for (TiXmlNode* tinyChild = tinySet->FirstChild(); tinyChild; tinyChild = tinyChild->NextSibling())
        {
            if (tinyChild)
            {
                if (tinyChild->TINYXML_ELEMENT != tinyChild->Type())
                {
                    continue;
                }
                //TODO: Change this to reflect my xml structure. Past this point I'm not sure what I'm doing.
                tinyData = tinyChild->ToElement()->Attribute("Name");

                if (strcmp(tinyData.c_str(), "Name") == 0)
                {
                    localName = tinyChild->ToElement()->FirstChild()->Value();
                }
                else if (strcmp(tinyData.c_str(), "Age") == 0)
                {
                    localAge = tinyChild->ToElement()->FirstChild()->Value();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Unrelated: `strcmp(tinyData.c_str(), "Name") == 0` is the same as `tinyData == "Name"` but with a lot less fuss.

Comment: I don't know this API, but I'd be very surprised if `tinyData = tinyChild->ToElement()->Attribute("Name");` didn't return the value of the "Name" attribute. I don't think you need more testing and messing around. What you should need to do is ensure `Attribute` didn't return `NULL` before putting it in a `string` ([very bad](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) to try and make a `string` from a null pointer). If you got NULL, there is no "Name" attribute, otherwise you should have a pointer to a null-terminated `char` array containing "myName" that you can put into a `string`

Comment: I don't have an attribute in my XML structure. The snippet of code was given to me to get me started, but I'm still lost .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uhoh. That API looks hypercomplicated. TinyXML is geared for performance, but nothing else really.

So. Choosing your library is the most important step: [What XML parser should I use in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387610/what-xml-parser-should-i-use-in-c)

Now, in most circumstances where you can use TinyXML you can use PugiXML. PugiXML has a much friendlier interface. Most importantly it's less error-prone (w.r.t resource management, e.g.). It also supports XPath.

That helps a lot here. Because, in my humble opinion, as soon as you find yourself looping over nodes¹, the case is lost. You'll end up with [christmas tree code](https://mattcbaker.com/posts/refactoring-nested-if-statements/) and it's really hard to get correct or maintain.

Here's my take using PugiXML:

```
#include <pugixml.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace pugi;

int main() {
    xml_document doc;
    doc.load_file("input.xml");
    
    auto rotary = doc.root();
    // rotary.print(std::cout); // prints the entire thing

    auto name = rotary
        .select_single_node("//UserInformation/Name/text()")
        .node();
    auto age =  rotary
        .select_single_node("//UserInformation/Age/text()")
        .node();

    std::cout << "\nName is " << name.value() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Age is " << age.text().as_double() << "\n";
}
```

It's still tricky (mostly the part where element text is child `text` nodes which you can get using different methods). But at least the end result is reasonably maintainable. Oh, it prints:

```
<Rotary>
    <UserInformation>
        <Name>myName</Name>
        <Age>42.7</Age>
    </UserInformation>
</Rotary>

Name is myName
Age is 42.7
```

There are no leaks in this code.

---

(¹not even mentioning the atrocious interface that TinyXML uses...)

Comment: Thank you very much! PugiXML is much easier to use for me than TinyXML.