# How to convert XML file to HTML tables using C++ code?

Tags: html, c++, xml, c++11

I have an XML file. I want to convert it to HTML file and represent it like an HTML table using my C++ application. Is there any C++ library which I can use to parse the XML file and create an HTML file?

Example:

```
<breakfast_menu>
<food>
    <name>Belgian Waffles</name>
    <price>$5.95</price>
    <description>
   Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup
   </description>
    <calories>650</calories>
</food>
<food>
    <name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</name>
    <price>$7.95</price>
    <description>
    Light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream
    </description>
    <calories>900</calories>
</food>
<food>
    <name>Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles</name>
    <price>$8.95</price>
    <description>
    Belgian waffles covered with assorted fresh berries and whipped cream
    </description>
    <calories>900</calories>
</food>
```

I want to give this file to my application and it should output an HTML file in which the entries are represented in table form.

| name | price | description | calories |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Belgian Waffle | 5.95 | Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup | 650 |

Comment: Did you do any research on this yet?

Comment: It is better to use XSLT for such tasks. This way you don't need any additional libraries. Just call XSLT transformation from c++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XSLT to convert input XML into HTML table.

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="html"/>

    <xsl:template match="/breakfast_menu">
        <table border="1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>name</th>
                    <th>price</th>
                    <th>description</th>
                    <th>calories</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <xsl:for-each select="food">
                    <tr>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="price"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="description"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="calories"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks but I want to do it within my C++ application. Is there a way?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387610/what-xml-parser-should-i-use-in-c

Comment: Yes you can do it in C but it will be a lot more code than the XSLT solution and much harder to maintain.