# How to Load and Read/Write XML file into GTK+ application Using C++?

Tags: c++, xml, gtk, gtk3, gnome

I am working on a gtk+ application in which is coded in C++ and I wants to load and work on XML data for showing the information and edits. But I dont know how to load and read/write into xml file in gtk.I am one month beginner in gtk+ development so if anyone know please help.

Comment: You're looking for XML parsing libraries. There's some discussion of options [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387610/what-xml-parser-should-i-use-in-c?lq=1). Not sure how current they are. It sounds like TinyXML2 or PugiXML might be appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for your response @NathanPierson ...these mentioned xml parser is campatible with gtk+?  I havent worked with gtk+ and xml before thats why I am asking.

Comment: Well, I don't know exactly how GTK factors into this. If you're just trying to load, parse, and edit a single simple file, and then ultimately that file is getting handed off to a GTK function, either of those should be fine. If there's some more complicated requirement, you'll need to describe what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: Thanks @NathanPierson I will explore your given link It has much more then I expected and thanks for your response.